# How to make AWS SNS confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I already subscribed the SNS and now trying to send SNS confirmation.
Therefore, I referring the AWS documentation **Confirm Subscription to a Topic** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples-subscribing-unsubscribing-topics.html

However, I got invalid Protocol and Endpoint param error using that sample code.

SNS subscribe code

```
try {
            $result = $sns->subscribe([
                'Protocol' => $protocol,
                'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
                'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
                'TopicArn' => $topic,
            ]);
            Debugbar::info($result);
        } catch (AwsException $e) {
            // output error message if fails
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: What exactly have you setup? You can post screenshots if you want.

Comment: @Marcin I uploaded the code. The code above working fine and subscribe the SNS successfully. Now I have no idea how to confirm the HTTPS endpoint subscription.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/sns-send-http.html#subscribe-your-http-https-endpoint-to-your-amazon-sns-topic) is info on how to confirm http subscriptions.